# Performing arithmetic involving non-terminating BigDecimals

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

When dividing a BigDecimal, it's possible that the result will be non-terminating. As a result, you must provide a MathContext or RoundingMode/scale as part of the division operation. However, depending on the order of operations in your arithmetic, the loss of precision can result in discrepancies.

How can discrepancies due to precision loss (such as example shown below) be avoided when using BigDecimals? Curious to know how others have dealt with this type of issue.

**Example:**

```
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal("29.14");
BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal("12");
BigDecimal v3 = new BigDecimal("75");
System.out.println(v1.divide(v2, MathContext.DECIMAL64).multiply(v3).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
// Prints: 182.12
System.out.println(v1.multiply(v3).divide(v2, MathContext.DECIMAL64).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
// Prints: 182.13
```

In the example above, depending on the order of operations, the result changes.

Before running into this example while testing, I would have never considered the order of BigDecimal operations to be a problem. Now, I'm left with this dilemma :)

Comment: BigDecimal dont have precision loss, indeterminate numbers are those that such division cannot be exact and ends with a periodic that approachs to the result such 1 / 3 that results in 0.333333...

Comment: I think a good approach is not rounding the result and simply cutting at some

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos the problem is you can't do `BigInteger.divide` to get the exact value of e.g. 1/3. You *have* to specify where to cut off, resulting in unavoidable precision loss.

Comment: I dont think we dont have tools for such problem, but found that multyplying instead of dividing dont produce such errors:         BigDecimal o = new BigDecimal("2");
        BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal("0.3333");
        BigDecimal t2 = new BigDecimal("3");

        /* System.out.println(o.divide(t2)); */ //RuntimeException
        System.out.println(o.multiply(t)); // works

Comment: Set the precision for your divisions to about 5-6 digits higher than you want to have in the end. I thought many more "extra digits" would be required, but it turned out that 5-6 digits are generally enough. In the end, scale down to the required precision. Note that only divisions are a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a common problem with floating point arithmetics, be it binary or decimal: a division may be unaccurate. So when you have to do a multiplication and a division, if you do the division first and the result is unaccurate, when you later do the multiplication you multiply the error of the first result.

In you example, the exact result is 182.125 which is just in the border to be rounded to 182.13 . When you make the division first, the exact result of 29.14/12 is 2.428333...

With the 16 digits of DECIMAL64, it is rounded to 2.428333333333333 and when it is multiplied with 75, it gives 182.12499999999997 which will be rounded to 182.12

So what can be done here:

- do the multiplications first if there is no risk of overflow, and the division last. For example for `a/b*c/d` you should compute `(a*c)/(b*d)`
- try to add one precision digit when you use decimals. Here you should use a precision of 3 decimal digits as the initial numbers are given with 2 ones. The result would have been 182.125 in both cases

But anyway, as soon as you have not exact results, there is a risk that you get a rounding error, it is inherent to floating point computation.

Comment: Or simply use a higher precision and round to DECIMAL64 at the end. Of course, if possible, always do multiplications/additions/subtractions before you divide, as you said, but the higher precision helps a lot. It is even enough to be able to calculate sines or cosines with simple Taylor series (yes, I know there are better ways).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain your section approach? If I use a precision of 3 for all numbers, I end up getting 182.100 as the result for the first order of operations.

Comment: "Or simply use a higher precision and round to DECIMAL64" -- This is an interesting approach. Could use DECIMAL128 in the division, and then round to DECIMAL64, followed by a round to 2 decimals:     v1.divide(v2, MathContext.DECIMAL128).multiply(v3,MathContext.DECIMAL64).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP). The problem still exists, but it greatly reduces the odds of it happening.